# Ipython ? not working

Tags: python, ipython, canopy

I installed Canopy on my ubuntu 12.04 lts OS.

I am mainly using this for data analysis. I realised that the ? operator is not working.

For example. When I declare a integer b = 0 in the terminal and type b? it comes up with the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f4e05a8c28c4> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'pinfo d')

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2134         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2135         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2136         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2137 
   2138     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython    /core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2060                 args.append(sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals)
   2061             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2062                 result = fn(*args)
   2063             return result
   2064 

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/namespace.pyc in pinfo(self, parameter_s, namespaces)

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    189     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    190     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 191         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    192 
    193         if callable(arg):

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/namespace.pyc in pinfo(self, parameter_s, namespaces)
     56         else:
     57             self.shell._inspect('pinfo', oname, detail_level=detail_level,
---> 58                                 namespaces=namespaces)
     59 
     60     @line_magic

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in _inspect(self, meth, oname, namespaces, **kw)
   1464                 pmethod(info.obj, oname, formatter)
   1465             elif meth == 'pinfo':
-> 1466                 pmethod(info.obj, oname, formatter, info, **kw)
   1467             else:
   1468                 pmethod(info.obj, oname)

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/oinspect.pyc in pinfo(self, obj, oname, formatter, info, detail_level)
    557         # Finally send to printer/pager:
    558         if displayfields:
--> 559             page.page(self._format_fields(displayfields))
    560 
    561     def info(self, obj, oname='', formatter=None, info=None, detail_level=0):

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/page.pyc in page(strng, start, screen_lines, pager_cmd)
    182     if screen_lines <= 0:
    183         try:
--> 184             screen_lines += _detect_screen_size(use_curses, screen_lines_def)
    185         except (TypeError, UnsupportedOperation):
    186             print >>io.stdout, str_toprint

/home/marco/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/page.pyc in _detect_screen_size(use_curses, screen_lines_def)
    108 
    109         # Proceed with curses initialization
--> 110         scr = curses.initscr()
    111         screen_lines_real,screen_cols = scr.getmaxyx()
    112         curses.endwin()

/home/marco/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/curses/__init__.pyc in initscr()
     31     # instead of calling exit() in error cases.
     32     setupterm(term=_os.environ.get("TERM", "unknown"),
---> 33               fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
     34     stdscr = _curses.initscr()
     35     for key, value in _curses.__dict__.items():

error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database
```

Comment: what do you get from: `python -c 'import curses; print (curses.initscr(), curses.endwin())'`?

Comment: I get the following message from the terminal when I try to run your command :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/marco/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/curses/__init__.py", line 33, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database